# Hyperledger Fabric: Listen to Datastream, while submit transaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

When I invoke a new transaction with the SDK/ or without, what is the best way to find out the communication from the client to the peer. I want to follow in detail what's submitted and what the peer sents back later.

With wireshark, I had problems due to TLS,gRPC/pb.
Is there a way to listen to all messages and traffic sent?

As far as I understood it the gRPC Framework is used for communication between client, peers and orderer **only** in Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options you could pursue.

1. Since Hyperledger Fabric is OSS, you can simply modify the code to inspect the message and log or dump the data at the gRPC service implementations.  For instance: the [`ProcessProposal` gRPC service](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos/blob/54779b223b6fa179cdd2f98239d3c9e484642ca7/peer/peer.proto#L16) is implemented [in endorser.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/6626a86d027538ec5abda834230525dab4de70f3/core/endorser/endorser.go#L296).
2. You could disable TLS, and use the tooling you referenced in your post (like wireshark).  You can disable TLS in [core.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/6626a86d027538ec5abda834230525dab4de70f3/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L247) for the peer, or in [orderer.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/6626a86d027538ec5abda834230525dab4de70f3/sampleconfig/orderer.yaml#L23) for the orderer.
3. You could attempt to get something like [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) and configure the CLI/SDK to trust its TLS cert.  Unfortunately, it looks like the currently released version [has some problems with gRPC](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/2474), so you might need a custom build to make this work.

> As far as I understood it the gRPC Framework is used for communication between client, peers and orderer only in Fabric.

Most of the client APIs are indeed gRPC based.  A few, like the operations endpoint for setting log levels and collecting metrics are REST based.