# Insights + Evaluating gRPC Message Flow Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

**I want to examine the gRPC Message Flow from invoking a smart contract until a block is created:**

I exactly want to examine these steps (the used message stream) I later found composed in a whole block (If I understand it right these parts are only put together at the end in a block some adds):

**Invoke call of a Chaincode e.g. Change Value "a" to "10" in using CLI:**

```
 1. CLI sends Proposal to Endorser -> [SignedProposal with Signature, Proposal:(Header+Payload)]

 2. Endorser sends Proposal Response back to CLI -> [ProposalResponse with its Endorsement,
    PropRespPayload] 

 3. CLI packs endorsements into Transaction + sends them to orderer for block creation

 4. Block is created by orderer + validation of sign.
```

What is the fastest way to fetch them?

**What I did:**

1. (*Not good, rather laborious*) Try to modificate code in binaries like "peer" where gRPC is handled, rebuild images:

My problem is that I am able to build and modificate the binaries like the peer executable (which is used in images and started inside a docker container like the peer), but I finally want to use them and make us of the sample projects like first-network, where I can invoke a transaction and log with own implementations what is gRPCed there. What I could do here and what is very time consuming is to rebuild all images and later make all sample files fitting to the new environement and implement this parts, but I think there have to be a faster way of evaluating the message flow (with the output of the full gRPC message stream /decoded and encoded).

2. (*I think the best way for now*):
   I have not discovered faster ways yet (am new to Go and gRPC), instead of logging what gRPC is sending with wireshark and try to decode it (but it won't work for all parts, cause of incomplete messages or  afraid). For some parts (proving sign) it is necessary that I have the marshalled version of some objects. This is what I need the most actually, but therefore I need to understand the gRPC content of the wiresharked parts :)

Do you have any suggestions for me? Would you rather go on with Way1 or Way2? Or am I on a too complicated way to fix it?

Is there a faster way existing? I mean I need the unmarshaled parts, but also the marshaled content of some objects and I have the proto files (when these are the correct ones for the logging parts I did in wireshark while an invoke was take place).

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own gRPC api by following those simple steps:

- 1st you need to make a signed proposal. To make a signed proposal, you can get idea from [**endorser_test.go file**](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/core/endorser/endorser_test.go).
- To send a signed proposal to peer for endorsement, you need a ProcessProposal gRPC call where you can get the response from endorsing peer and your need to create a EndorserClient too.
- After that you need to collect all endorsements from peers and have to make signed envelope
- To make a signed envelope, you can take help from **[txutils.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/protoutil/txutils_test.go)** file
- To send a signed envelope to orderers you need to broadcast your envelope to orderers with Send gRPC call where we need to create a AtomicBroadcastClient.

Comment: This is correct! I also discovered these parts out, proposal.go, propresp and txutils, together with its proto descr.. At the end the orderer makes its broadcast to the peers and here the gossip starts.

I afraid this costs time, but it should work.

Comment: Where I am unsure is what happens behind, I mean the messages that are send. I understand the process for proposal leads to propresponse, cli collects resps, forwards it to orderer (all these parts are gRPC msgs, as far as I can see, I also logged them in wireshark, decoded them, but they are splitted, so there is a time intensive compose process needed... and I further need to interpret these to work with). I`d like to look inside of them but only strings like msps, and its certs are clearly visible (not marshaled).

Comment: Is there a further message stream/system existing inside of fabric? There is only gRPC, gossip and discovery prot. or? But I found parts of message.proto in older versions, but am unsure how its used. A message struct with type and payload. I could imagine that this is the gRPC message itself that is implemented in the payload here (to send the proposal, propresponse and so on), but I have to check this further.

Answer (score 0):

This seems closely related to the [question you posted a month or so ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61521885/hyperledger-fabric-listen-to-datastream-while-submit-transaction/61550276#61550276).

As you point out, if you wish to do things like validate signatures, you will need the marshaled form of the messages, but if you wish to inspect the messages, you will need to unmarshal them.

I would think that option 1 (modifying the code to dump the information you need) is still the most useful.  As you can perform whatever serialization, persistence, or analysis inside the code itself.  If you simply store these data structures to disk via something like wire-shark, then you will need to track them, parse them, etc., which seems like more work to me.

If you have marshaled messages on disk, you can try using a tool like [configtxlator](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/commands/configtxlator.html) to unmarshal the messages to a more friendly JSON format, if you have tracked the appropriate type, though this still seems more difficult than simply injecting code to me.

Comment: Also, thank for your support. I`ve also tried this out and had problems in recomposing and to further work on with this data. I used the wireshark way. But to work further with the data is not possible so far, cause unmarshaling fails. I will further try ways here, but maybe there is another problem the reason for, cause for example if I use proto responses to decode with its proto file, it fails do decode. This is why I think that there is a surounding message existing that wraps the grpc message part of e.g. responses.proto. A sample output in the doc would be helpful to see what is inside.

Comment: When I found it out, I will add it to the official docu cause a lot of developer have problems with this part of fabric and its unclear messaging structure

Comment: You can see the gRPC service definitions in the protos themselves.  For instance, for the endorser service: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos/blob/9944f8f73cfe0585a477f4b7d56a090374d0c7b6/peer/peer.proto#L15-L17

Fabric does no special wrapping or encoding, this is all handed by gRPC.  You can see details on the actual wire format here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md